# Unable to access software center

Tags: software-center

When i'm trying to go to software center for an application it says :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc-nox
```

Comment: Have you done an upgrade to this Ubuntu version, or a fresh install? Seems like the former.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Universe repo and try again!

**HOWTO**

You can quick enable from a terminal with this command:

`sudo software-properties-gtk -e universe`

After that issue:

`sudo apt-get update`

and try again!